# how to prevent repetitive shuffle of my array using onClick

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, render

I need your fresh eyes to help me.

I have a set of answers in my array which I shuffle on the first render.

My problem here, is that I know if i am clicking on one of the answer, the setState will re-render and consequently re-shuffle my array which i dont want.

You can have a look at my code below:

```js
export default class extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      user: this.props.user,
      token: this.props.token,
      data: this.props.data,
      count: 0,
      select: undefined
    }
    this.changeQuestion = this.changeQuestion.bind(this);
    this.onCorrect = this.onCorrect.bind(this);
    this.onFalse = this.onFalse.bind(this);
  }

  static async getInitialProps({req, query}) {

    const id = query.id;
    const authProps = await getAuthProps(req, 'Country/Questions?theory=' + id)
    return authProps

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.user === undefined) {
      Router.push('/login')
    }
  }

  changeQuestion() {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1,
      select: undefined
    })
  }

  onCorrect() {
    this.setState({
      select: true
    })
  }

  onFalse() {
    this.setState({
      select: true
    })
  }


  mixAnswers() {
    const answer = this.props.data.Properties.Elements

    const answers = answer[this.state.count].Properties.Answers

    const answersObj = answers.reduce((ac, el, i) => {

      ac.push(
        <p key={i} onClick={i === 0
          ? this.onCorrect
          : this.onFalse} className={i === 0
          ? 'exercices__answers--correct'
          : 'exercices__answers--false'}>{el}</p>
      )

      return ac
    }, [])

    const answersShuffled = answersObj.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())

    return answersShuffled;
  }








  render() {
    const {user, token, data} = this.state
    const answer = this.props.data.Properties.Elements
    const answers = answer[this.state.count].Properties.Answers
    return (

      <div>
        {user !== undefined
          ? <Layout user={this.state.user}>
              <div>
                {answer[this.state.count].Properties.Sources !== undefined
                  ? <img src={answer[this.state.count].Properties.Sources[0].URL}/>
                  : ''}
                <h1>{answer[this.state.count].Properties.Question}</h1>
                {this.mixAnswers().map((el, i) => <p key={i} onClick={el.props.onClick} className={this.state.select !== undefined
                  ? el.props.className
                  : ''}>{el.props.children}</p>)
                }
              <p>{answer[this.state.count].Properties.Description}</p>

              </div>
              <button onClick={this.changeQuestion}>Next Question</button>
            </Layout>
          : <h1>Loading...</h1>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Obviously, the way I am using the 'this.mixAnswers()' method is the issue. How can I prevent it to re-render then re-shuffle this array of questions.
PS: dont pay attention about onCorrect() and onFalse().

Comment: Why don't you just randomise the list in `componentDidMount()` and then place it in state, and then use that in `mixAnswers()`? Otherwise the shuffle will happen every time  `mixAnswers()` is called in the `render()` method.

Comment: Why are you shuffling it inside `render()` in the first place? `render()` isn't supposed to change the state.

Comment: ok thanks so much guyz . I found out how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure the logic that shuffle the answers is called only once, you can get this behavior on ComponentWillMount or ComponentDidMount, then you save them in the state of the component and in the render function instead of

```
{this.mixAnswers().map((el, i) => <p key={i} onClick={el.props.onClick} className={this.state.select !== undefined
              ? el.props.className
              : ''}>{el.props.children}</p>)
}
```

You use `this.state.answers.map()`...